# How to load .OBJ and .MTL using ThreeJS? (HTML)

Tags: html, css, three.js

I'm trying to load a 3D globe into my HTML site using a ThreeJS script (found below) But it's stitched together with code from other sources, meaning the camera is mapped to `MouseX` and `MouseY` positions. I want the object to sit in the center of the page with a simple slow spin, but every time I try and achieve this the object vanishes.

The Javascript:

```
<script>
        var container;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


        init();
        animate();


        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 5, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );
            camera.position.z = 250;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.8 );
            scene.add( ambientLight );

            var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFF1CF, 0.6 , 0 );

            camera.add( pointLight );
            scene.add( camera );

            var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
            manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

                console.log( item, loaded, total );

            };


            var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                }
            };

            var onError = function ( xhr ) {;
            };

            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.load('planet.mtl', function(materials) {
        materials.preload();
        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.load('planet.obj', function(object) {
         object.position.y = 0;
         scene.add(object);
        }, onProgress, onError);
        });

            //

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {alpha: true});
           renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                     document.addEventListener( 'mouseclick', onmousedown, false);

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX );
            mouseY = ( event.clientY );

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

        }

        function render() {

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code a little bit,

In the 'init' function, change the object loading logic as follows

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
mtlLoader.load( 'planet.mtl', function(materials) {
    materials.preload();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.load( 'planet.obj', function( object ){
        object.position.set( 0, 0, 0 ); // set the position as (0,0,0)
        globe = object; // globe is the object to be added to the scene
        scene.add(globe);
        animate(); //call the animate function only after the object is loaded
    }, onProgress, onError);
} );
```

And change the render method,

```
function render() {
    globe.rotation.y += 0.01; // this will rotate the object
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!